# can this code be written in two lines?

Tags: python

I have a feeling that using the setdefault method or lamda that this code can be written in two lines:

```
variables = ['a','b','c','d']
for value in indefinite_dict.values():
    str1 = immediate_instantiation.get(value)
    if str1 == None:
        immediate_instantiation.update({value:variables[0]})
        del variables[0]
```

It loops through the values of the indefinite_dict and puts them in and if that value is not already a key in the immediate instantiation dict then it adds that as an entry into that dict with a value of the first member of the variables list and deletes the first member of the variables list.

Comment: What is `variables[0]`?

Comment: it's a list of letters.

Comment: The added context of what `variables` is and what you need it to contain might help create a better solution.

Comment: see edit above..

Comment: I don't get this `immediate_instantiation.update({str1:variables[0]})` as `str1` is always `None` at this point so you're just overwritting the same (`None`) key.

Comment: I don't understand what this is doing. You have two dicts that you don't show, but then you `del variables[0]`... well if you're iterating through the dictionary then you will get items from that dict in random order, and deleting `variables[0]` makes me think you assume you'll get things from the dictionary in order.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place for code golf. We spun off a [whole separate StackExchange site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) *specifically* because questions that are principally puzzles (and, yes, "what's the shortest way to write X?" is a puzzle) aren't welcome here: Our scope is limited to **practical** problems, and prioritizing terseness over readability, performance characteristics, &c. is inherently impractical.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re okay with values in `variables` being deleted even if a corresponding key already exists in `immediate_instantiation` *when that key has the same value*, you’re right that you can do it with only `setdefault`:

```
for value in indefinite_dict.values():
    if immediate_instantiation.setdefault(value, variables[0]) is variables[0]:
        del variables[0]
```

To get it down to two lines without any other context takes a different (and kind of unpleasant) approach, though:

```
updates = (v for v in indefinite_dict.values() if v not in immediate_instantiation)
immediate_instantiation.update({v: variables.pop(0) for v in updates})
```

And `indefinite_dict` had better be an `OrderedDict` – otherwise you’re removing variables in a potentially random order! (Don’t rely on Python 3.6’s dict representation for this.)

If you don’t need `variables` after this *and* `variables` is guaranteed to be at least as long as `updates`, a non-mutating solution is much cleaner, note:

```
updates = (v for v in indefinite_dict.values() if v not in immediate_instantiation)
immediate_instantiation.update(zip(updates, variables))
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
immediate_instantiation.update({value: variables.pop(0) for value in indefinite_dict.values() if value not in immediate_instantiation})
```

Comment: Came here to post same solution as yours. Don't know why you are minused.